# creating stored procedure in mysql to generate roll numbers in each batch

Tags: mysql, sql, select, stored-procedures, sql-order-by

I have created user table with columns id,name, batch, rollnumber

I want to create a stored procedure which will generate roll number per batch.

Suppose I have 100 students and five batches(A,B,C,D,E).

It should generate roll numbers 1-20 in each batch.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Hi! Welcome to Stackoverflow. To get an answer you will have to provide a little more information. Like what have you tried? Are you getting errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT u.id, u.name, u.batch, IF(@batch = (@batch := u.batch), @rollNo := @rollNo + 1, @rollNo := 1) rollNo
FROM userTable u, (SELECT @batch:='', @rollNo:=1) A
ORDER BY u.batch, u.name
```